# Live wallpaper CPU usage

Tags: android, android-studio, cpu-usage, live-wallpaper, battery

I have created a live wallpaper that roughly uses as much as 30% of CPU and that's only when it is active (main launcher interface) but when an app is running or the phone is locked it does use 0% of CPU... is It bad that my LW uses 30% when active ?
phones tested on:

-note 2: all cores active @1.6GHz @ 30% usage

-LG G2: TWO cores actives @2.3GHz @ 30% usage

-galaxy pocket:one core active @800MHz @30% usage

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't want to download a wallpaper that uses that much CPU, so I would say anything that uses more than 10% is too much. but that's just my opinion.

It also depends on what platforms you are targeting.